# Capture video from multiple cameras in Processing

Tags: camera, processing, video-capture, capture

I am trying to display in the same Processing window 2 (or more) different captures from cameras attached to the computer: the default built-in camera and a USB Camera.

It seems that if I start both cameras at a time nothing is displayed. Would it even be possible to have 2 (or more) different captures ?
Here's the code:

```
import processing.video.*;
Capture camA;
Capture camB;
String[] cameras;

void setup(){
cameras=Captures.list();
camA = new Capture(this,1280,960,cameras[15]);
camB = new Capture(this,1280,960,cameras[1]);
camA.start(); 
camB.start();
}
void draw() {
  image(camA, 100, 100, 360,240);
  image(camB, 500, 100, 360,240);
}

void captureEvent(Capture c) {
  if(c==camA){   
    camA.read();
  }else if(c==camB) {
    camB.read();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by choosing other camera resolutions from the list. Having both at the higher resolutions won't render them. It worked with one at 640x320 and the other at 320x180, which was enough for me.

Comment: I imagine you first checked the max. resolution of each camera (they may be different). One wild guess is that at max resolution each camera will have need a higher USB bandwidth. If the usb port you used for the USB camera is on the same USB hub as your built-in camera on your laptop's motherboard, they'll share the same 'data pipe'. Either check the datasheet of your laptops motherboard and usb hubs/controllers or try different usb ports for the USB camera ? You might be able to use a higher resolution. Another alternative might be using an powered USB hub if you have one around. Bafta!